# what's the "ip address range" when you create TPU node?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tpu

what's the "ip address range" when you create TPU node?

and it always give the following error;

：Quota limit 'TPUV3sPerProjectPerRegionForTPUAPI,TPUV3sPerProjectPerZoneForTPUAPI' has been exceeded.
 Limit: 0,0 in region us-central1,zone us-central1-a.

Answer (score 0):

The IP depends on what (if any) other nodes you have created and what address ranges they occupy; if you use the [ctpu tool](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/ctpu-reference) it should handle the configuration step for you.

The second error is unrelated and indicates that you're trying to create more nodes than you have quota for (in this case you don't appear to have any in the region you are specifying).